# Checking the value in the UITextfiled

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I have a UITextfield and I need to check the value entered in it is in a particular range (say between 2 and 10). can anyone help with a sample code?

I was using this code

```
if( [[textfieldobject.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                         [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length] != 0 && 
                         [[textfieldobject.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length] <= 2 &&
                         [[textfieldobject.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length] > 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the string value to an int, then check the range.  intValue will always return a valid int conversion (zero if anything non-numeric).   Just be aware that if someone types "a10", the result will be 0 and in the code below, it would fall within range.

```
int convertedValue = [textFieldObject.text intValue];
if (convertedValue >= 0 && convertedValue <= 10) {
    NSLog(@"In range");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Out of range");
}
```

You can prevent out of range chars as they are being typed by overriding the UITextFieldDelegate delegate:

```
shouldChangeCharactersInRange
```

or override this delegate and run your check, then pop a notice and make the user edit.

```
textFieldDidEndEditing
```

Comment: if( [[textfieldobject.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length] != 0 || (( players > 2) && (players < 6 ))) 
   {
    code...
      }
   
    else
    {
        code...
    }   i gave like this but it always enters the else part

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **length** property for this.